# Using WebSockets with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, websocket, next.js

I'm wondering what's the best approach to connect into my WebSockets server using Next.js' pages? I'd like that the user could navigate through the pages with one connection, and when he closes the page he also closes the WebSockets connection. I tried using React's Context API:

```
const WSContext = createContext(null);

const Wrapper = ({ children }) => {
  const instance = WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000/ws");

  return <WSContext.Provider value={instance}>{children}</WSContext.Provider>;
};

export const useWS = () => useContext(WSContext);

export default Wrapper;
```

It works great, but it does not when it comes to creating a connection. The basic `new WebSocket` syntax is not working, so I must use a third-party library, like `react-use-websocket` which I dislike. What's also disturbing is that I cannot close the connection. The Context simply does not know when the page is closed, and also the library does not provide a hook for closing connections.

I would like to know what's the best approach when it comes to handling WebSockets connection in Next.js.

Comment: Not quite understand the question. The connection will be closed automatically when the page is closed. Why `new WebSocket` does not work? Do you have some error?

Comment: @Danila Next.js does server-side rendering and static site generation. The WebSocket API is not available when the page is initially rendered. They'd have to call `new Websocket()` in something like a `useEffect()` hook to instantiate it client-side or use some other way to defer instantiation of the WebSocket.

Comment: @Calvin right, but if I'd use a hook which would create new WebSocket connection I would create a new connection every time I need to use the WebSocket, isn't it? That's what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

There are multiple things that need to be done in order for ws to work on Next.js.

Firstly, it is important to realize where do I want my ws code to run. React code on Next.js runs in two environments: On the server (when building the page or when using ssr) and on the client.

Making a ws connection at page build time has little utility, thats why I will cover client-side ws only.

The global Websocket class is a browser only feature and is not present on the server. Thats why we need to prevent any instantiation until the code is run in the browser. One simple way to do so would be:

```
export const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined";
```

```
export const wsInstance = isBrowser ? new WebSocket(...) : null;
```

Also, you do not need to use react context for holding the instance, it is perfectly possible to keep it at global scope and import the instance, unless you wish to open the connection lazily.

If you still decide to use react context (or initialize the ws client anywhere in the react tree), it is important to **memoize** the instance, so that it isn't created on every update of your react node.

```
const wsInstance = useMemo(() => isBrowser ? new WebSocket(...) : null, []);
```

or

```
const [wsInstance] = useState(() => isBrowser ? new WebSocket(...) : null);
```

Any event handler registrations created in react should be wrapped inside a `useEffect` with a return function which removes the event listener, this is to prevent memory leaks, also, a dependency array should be specified. If your component is unmounted, the `useEffect` hook will remove the event listener as well.

If you wish to reinitailize the ws and dispose of the current connection, then it is possible to do something similar to the following:

```
const [wsInstance, setWsInstance] = useState(null);

// Call when updating the ws connection
const updateWs = useCallback((url) => {
   if(!browser) return setWsInstance(null);
   
   // Close the old connection
   if(wsInstance?.readyState !== 3)
     wsInstance.close(...);

   // Create a new connection
   const newWs = new WebSocket(url);
   setWsInstance(newWs);
}, [wsInstance])


// (Optional) Open a connection on mount
useEffect(() => {
 if(isBrowser) { 
   const ws = new WebSocket(...);
   setWsInstance(ws);
 }

 return () => {
  // Cleanup on unmount if ws wasn't closed already
  if(ws?.readyState !== 3) 
   ws.close(...)
 }
}, [])
```

Comment: Can `new WebSocket()` run on the clientside without extra configuration? I'm getting this error: invalid 'instanceof' operand URL because `if(address instance of URL)` fails. URL is undefined. I've imported WebSocket as `const WebSocket = require("ws");` and tried import {WebSocket} from "ws";

Comment: @CrippledTable Websocket in the answer refers to a [web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) and is available globally, no imports needed.

Comment: Thank you. I had tunnel vision. I was recently trying to use the ws npm package on the client side. After a spiritual journey it dawned on me how naive this was, and I see now how this works.

Comment: Thank you @FilipKaštovský I spent many hours figuring out what was wrong and finally found this!

Comment: @CrippledTable This is a tangential question, but do you happen to know if you could host a Next.Js websocket app on AWS Amplify? I know Vercel does not have native support for websockets, and was wondering if Amplify might..

Comment: @BudLinville that is the exact hosting infrastructure and tech stack that I used. I can't remember if there were any 'gotchas' to get it working, but it is possible.

Answer (score 3):

I configured context like this:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useMemo, useEffect, ReactNode } from 'react';

type WSProviderProps = { children: ReactNode; url: string };

const WSStateContext = createContext<WebSocket | null>(null);

function WSProvider({ children, url }: WSProviderProps): JSX.Element {
  const wsInstance = useMemo(
    () => (typeof window != 'undefined' ? new WebSocket(`ws://127.0.0.1:8001/ws${url}`) : null),
    []
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      wsInstance?.close();
    };
  }, []);

  return <WSStateContext.Provider value={wsInstance}>{children}</WSStateContext.Provider>;
}

function useWS(): WebSocket {
  const context = useContext(WSStateContext);

  if (context == undefined) {
    throw new Error('useWS must be used within a WSProvider');
  }

  return context;
}

export { WSProvider, useWS };
```